# Mac M1 - Unable to programmatically launch Appium using java appium client

Tags: appium, apple-m1, appium-java

Appium server is initiated and then throws Java.net Timeout exception

Comment: Try to check your setup with https://github.com/appium/appium-doctor . If everything is fine, please share your code that throws an error.

Comment: Appium doctor shows everything is fine. But when starting Appium server programmatically,  get “ [HTTP] Could not start REST http interface listener. The requested port may already be in use. Please make sure there is no other instance of this server running already.
Fatal Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use 0.0.0.0:4723”. But there is no other instance running. Same issue with Appium 1.22.0 and 1.22.2